# What is the significance of deity forms of navrathri?

Tags: goddess, navrathri, parvati

I know that Navrathri is 9 days occasion on which Goddess shows different deity forms each day. But I am not sure what is the significance of these nine deity forms and why Goddess decided to take these avatars?

I heard a story that Goddess Parvati was angry on lord Shiva for cutting head of lord Ganesha. From this anger, these nine avatars were emerged. But I am not sure to which extent it is true?

Comment: Why don't you search on the internet? you will find on wikipedia with all the refereces... Before asking do some research

Comment: The significance is given here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navratri

Comment: Nine forms are nine incranations of Shakti for various purposes

Comment: Lord Brahma is cited in the Markandey Purana as mentioning to Rishi Markandey that the first incarnation of Shakti was as Shailputri. Further incarnations of the Divine Mother are: Brahmcharñi, Chandraghanta, Kushmanda, Skandamata, Katyayani, Kalratri, Mahagauri and Siddhidatri in that order. These nine manifestations of Shakti, are worshipped as "Nava-Durga".

Comment: is your question about navratri or nav-durga incranations? Both are different questions.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I am asking for nav-durga incarnations. updated the question. I still think they are same though.

Comment: Okey now give me some time to explain them. i need to edit my answer

Comment: @Mr_Green: Although, this is a Pinterest page, the images show the significance of different deities on different days: https://in.pinterest.com/artoflivingnow/navratri-2015-at-bangalore-ashram/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Significance of Navaratri**

> Navaratri represents a celebration of the Goddess Amba(the Power). In gujarat(India) we do Aarti of Mother Amba all 9 days and play Garaba.
>
> Navaratri or Navadurga Parva happens to be the most auspicious and unique period of devotional sadhanas and worship of Shakti (the sublime, ultimate, absolute creative energy) of the Divine conceptualized as the Mother Goddess-Durga, whose worship dates back to prehistoric times before the dawn of the Vedic age.

Ref: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navratri)

**Significance of Nav - durga incarnations**

Name - worship day on navratri - Planet Govern

Shailputri - Day 1 - Moon

> After the self-immolation as Goddess Sati, Goddess Parvati took birth as the daughter of Lord Himalaya. In Sanskrit Shail means the mountain and due to which Goddess was known as Shailputri, the daughter of the mountain.

Brahmacharini - Day 2 - Mangal

> Goddess Parvati took birth at the home of Daksha Prajapati. In this form the Goddess Parvati was a great Sati and her unmarried form is worshipped as Goddess Brahmacharini.
>
> Goddess Brahmacharini did severe penance to get Lord Shiva as her husband. She performed hard austerity and due to which She was called Brahmacharini.

Chandraghanta - Day 3 - Shukra

> Goddess Chandraghanta is the married form the Goddess Parvati. After getting married to Lord Shiva Goddess Mahagauri started adorning her forehead with half Chandra and due to which Goddess Parvati was known as Goddess Chandraghanta.

Kushmanda - Day 4 - Aun

> Goddess Parvati started living inside the center of the Sun so that He can liberate energy to the universe. Since then Goddess is known as Kushmanda. Kushmanda is the Goddess who has the power and capability to live inside the Sun. The glow and radiance of her body is as luminous as that of the Sun.

Skandamata - Day 5 - Budha

> When Goddess Parvati became the mother of Lord Skanda (also known as Lord Kartikeya), Mata Parvati was known as Goddess Skandamata.

Katyayani - Day 6 - Brihaspati(Guru)

> To destroy demon Mahishasura, Goddess Parvati took the form of Goddess Katyayani. It was the most violent form of Goddess Parvati. In this form Goddess Parvati is also known as Warrior Goddess.

Kalratri - Day 7 - Shani

> When the Goddess Parvati removed outer golden skin to kill demons named Shumbha and Nishumbha, She was known as Goddess Kalaratri. Kalaratri is the fiercest and the most ferocious form of Goddess Parvati.

Mahagauri - Day 8 - Rahu

> According to Hindu mythologies, the Goddess Shailputri at the age of sixteen was extremely beautiful and was blessed with fair complexion. Due to her extreme fair complexion she was known as Goddess Mahagauri.

Siddhidatri - Day 9 - Ketu

> In the beginning of the universe Lord Rudra worshipped Adi-Parashakti for creation. It is believed that Goddess Adi-Parashakti had no form. The supreme Goddess of Power, Adi-Parashakti, appeared in the form of Siddhidatri from the left half of Lord Shiva.

**Reference :** Markandey Purana *(In [Durga Saptshati](http://www.freewebs.com/jaidurga/informationonmataji.htm), the Markandeya Purana depicts nine embodiments of the Goddess)*
**Also See:** [Nav Durga on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navadurga) and [Devi Mahatmya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi_Mahatmya)

Comment: If you're giving the Markandeya Puranas as a source, you should cite exactly where in the Markandeya Purana you're getting this information from?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I tried to give links but could not get exact link of "Durga Saptshati", if anybody find, one can edit it.. Thank You Keshavji for your advice.